# not able to add missing time strings to list

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to build a room booking application in java.  I have two variables of type `Date`,

`RoombookedFrom = Fri Nov 30 11:15:00 CET 2018`

`RoombookedTo = Fri Nov 30 12:30:00 CET 2018`

Based on these dates I am building new String arraylist and storing the timings in string format like this:

`ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();`

`list1 = [11:15, 12:30]`

But here I am willing to also store the missing timings for which room will not be available. e.g.

**What I want**

at every interval of `15 mins` i would like to build list from `11:15` to `12:30`

`list1 = [11:15, 11:30, 11:45, 12:00, 12:15, 12:30]`

so. e.g-2

if it is `list2 = [10:00, 11:15]` then output should be

`list2 = [10:00, 10:15, 10:30, 10:45, 11:00, 11:15]`

**What I tried**

I have tried making an approach for this where I would convert hours into numbers and calculate the difference but I don't understand how will i manage minutes here to correctly show up with the hours.

I also tried to search for this on stackoverflow but did not found any suitable solution

Comment: Have a look at `LocalTime`. It has the function `plusMinutes()` which lets you add minutes to the time very easily

Comment: okay i do that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it you may want to approach this from two perspectives.

First, you may want to create your own Hour class which will split string into hours and minutes and then add logic to to add 15 minutes ( It may be easier to check correctess since you could easily unit test this).

for example:

```
public class BookHour {

private int hours;
private int minutes;

BookHour(String formatedTime) {
    final String[] split = formatedTime.split(":");
    this.hours = Integer.valueOf(split[0]);
    this.minutes = Integer.valueOf(split[1]);
}

public int getHours() {
    return hours;
}

public int getMinutes() {
    return minutes;
}

public void setNextQuater() {
    // logic with changing hour and minutes
}
}
```

and test may look like:

```
public class BookHourTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldParse() {
        // given
        String time = "10:30";

        // when
        final BookHour bookHour = new BookHour(time);

        // then
        assertEquals(bookHour.getHours(), 10);
        assertEquals(bookHour.getMinutes(), 30);
    }

}
```

This way you could test all your needed asumptions and verify correctnes of your code.

However, java provides us with `LocalTime` class that may be usefull, and after you will be able to create it`s instance you may want to use its build int method plusMinutes(15)

```
 LocalTime bookTime = LocalTime.of(10, 30);
 LocalTime nextTime = bookTime.plusMinutes(15);
```

You will need additional handling of parsing from/to string but the logic regarding to adding minutes and handling it is already implemented so you do not have to worry about it`s correctness.

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried debugging with your method and it works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Below code will serve your purpose:

```
    @Test
public void test_stackOver() {
    String roomBookedFrom = "Fri Nov 30 11:15:00 CET 2018";
    String roomBookedTo = "Fri Nov 30 12:30:00 CET 2018";

    // Time Interval
    int minInterval = 15;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:SSS Z yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    // List to hold times
    List<String> times = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Date from = format.parse(roomBookedFrom);
        Date to = format.parse(roomBookedTo);
        String timeFrom = timeFormatter.format(from);
        String timeTo = timeFormatter.format(to);
        times.add(timeFrom);
        while (from.before(to)) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(from);
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minInterval);
            from = cal.getTime();
            times.add(timeFormatter.format(cal.getTime()));
        }
        times.add(timeTo);
        System.out.println(times);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you malay your solution looks good, but i chose to go with above answer because it fits properly with the context of my code and using `LocalTime` makes the minutes addition very short and precise